# about javascript, the result of expression:2<1<5, and reason?

Tags: javascript

today, I want achive:

```
 if(2 < 1 && 1 < 5) {
  //...some stuff
  }
```

then use math thought, write down `2 < 1 < 5`, because not use this pattern before, so look the result in console, now, I don't know the reason...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Is your question if you can write a "chained comparison" condition like `a<b<c` in Javascript?

Comment: i wish i can help you, but i really don't understand your english

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I suppose you're having problem with 2 < 1 < 5. If that's the case, the reason for all of that is that javascript first evaluates first part (2 < 1) to false (which can be thought of as 0) and then compares the false (or 0) with 5 (false < 5 is same as 0 < 5) and this evaluates to true. Therefore 2 < 1 < 5 is true.

Therefore 2 < 1 && 1 < 5 is false, but 2 < 1 < 5 is true so be careful about this.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple 2 < 1 = false < 5 = true

Answer (score 0):

`if(2 < 1 && 1 < 5)` is not equivalent to `if(2 < 1 < 5)`

First Condition will be evaluated like:

```
if(2 < 1 && 1 < 5) => if(false && true) => false
```

And the Second one like:

```
if(2 < 1 < 5) => if(0 < 5) => true  //false->0, true->1
```